# why does my variable has a greater value than I set?

Tags: arm, pipeline

Nowadays I'm working on ARM R7 and I found a situation I can't understand why.

Here's my code

```
if ( i++ > 2048 )
{
    panic(...); <----- here it has 2050 in its coredump.
}
```

When it gets panic'ed, it dumps the whole memory and I can load it up w/ T32.
By the way, the variable 'i' has 2050, not 2049.
I don't understand why it has such value. 
Someone can explain why it does, please...

PS : not multi-threaded.

Answer (score 3):

`i++` returns the *previous* value of the variable (while `++i` returns the new one). So, when `i` is 2049 (or any larger value), the condition is true and `panic` is called. When `i` was 2049 before, it will be 2050 after the `if`. It will always be incremented, regardless whether the condition was true or not. This is a fundamental rule in C, C++ and many other languages and has nothing to do with ARM or pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

A. Don't you want to do `while` not `if`.
B. Where do you initialize `i`?